# Ionic 2 calculate with Ngfor

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 2.

I Developed E-commerce app.

I need to calculate the Total amount.

Here is my template(Cart Page).

`PRICE_REGULAR` is Product Regular price and `PRICE_SALE` is product sale price.If I need to increase the product quantity I call the method  `countOperator(1,p)`

`Price` is Quantity and `PRICE_SALE` price.

```
<ion-row class="apply-coupon" *ngFor="let p of Cartproducts;let i=index">
    <ion-col col-4>
        <img src="{{p.P_IMAGES[0].URL}}" alt="product2">
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-8>
        <h1>{{p.P_TITLE}}</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
        <p class="code">Code: 123</p>

        <div>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col width-50>
                    <button ion-button outline small><ion-icon name="add" (click)="countOperator(1,p)"></ion-icon></button>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-label text-center>{{count}}</ion-label>
                <ion-col width-50>
                    <button ion-button outline small><ion-icon name="remove" (click)="countOperator(-1,p)"></ion-icon></button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>  
            <span><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">{{p.PRICE_REGULAR}}</span>

            <span *ngIf="Pid == p.C_ID"><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">{{Price}}</span>


            <span text-right><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">{{p.PRICE_SALE}}</span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button (click)="cancel(i)">Cancel X</button>
        </div>
    </ion-col>  
</ion-row>
```

Here is my countOperator method

```
countOperator(operator,s){
if(this.count >= 1){
      this.show1=false;
      this.count += operator;
      this.Price=this.count * Amount;
      this.change2(this.Price);
    }
    if(this.count < 1){
      this.show1=false;
      this.count = 1;
      this.Price=this.count * Amount;
      this.change2(this.Price);
    }
}
```

[image]

When I click the `+` icon increases the product quantity and amount.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: I can not understand your question clearly. What is your `total amount`? When do you want to caculate it?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I need Total amount.Which means List of a product displayed on cart page using ng for.Need Total product amount based on Price.

Comment: @Duannx.I updated my question.Kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with object.
Create a class product:

```
export class Product{
  priceRegular: number;
  priceSale: number;
  quantity: number;  
}

Cartproducts: Array<Product>=[...];
totoAmount = 0;
//countOperator should be passed product object:
countOperator(product:Product, number:number){
  product.quantity += number;
  this.totalAmount=0;
  for(let i=0; i<= this.Cartproducts.length; i++){
    this.totoAmount+= this.Cartproducts[i].quantity * this.Cartproducts[i].priceSale;
  }
  //Now you have total amount
  console.log(this.totalAmount);
}
```

Note that: this code above just is uncomplete example. You need to edit it to fit your case.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.But I don't understand ur answer.I tried this but my result is NaN